# Is it possible to maintain one global class instead of creating multiple model (NSObject) classes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model, nsobject

We are doing some changes in existing project of Objective-C. Now, we have to save and share to other classes which have different data for every class. So, there are 20 different classes, so, we are planning to create 20 model (NSObject) classes.

After checked this executing properly, seems not a good practise.

Its like each class data is completely different.

> Can anyone suggest us, is it good to create 20+ model (NSObject)
>   classes or is there any better solution for this?

Comment: you need to give more information!  If you have 20 completely different requirements, then you will need 20 completely different classes.  If each one is a slight variation on the others, then you may get away with a single class that encapsulates all of the properties and methods that you need in total - or something in between :-)

Comment: @Russell please check updated question. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: well, assuming you mean the data structure is different fo each class, then what you're really asking is - should I create a class to describe each object model, and the answer to that should be yes, no matter how many types there are.  If you have a hierarchy and you can inherit some methods or properties then you could always create some of your 20 from higher-order classes. (Animal -> Mammal -> dog / cat, etc.,)

Comment: There is no hierarchy. Its just 20 classes and each class has different objects. Here ny question is is it good to create 20 model classes to save or share each class?

Comment: We cant say without having more info about those 20 classes. Atleast you should put 2-3 classes and see how you can go forward with those 2-3 classes . Regarding your question, yes you can have one global class for all information, you just need to dump all properties in there, which makes it hard down the road to manage . I would always make small NSObject class and one big NSObject class that manages the small ones.